# Which verb form is correct?

Tags: tense, verbs

What I'm trying to convey is that there is a screen in an app, which is supposed to show jobs, but is not showing them.

Is this sentence correct:

The jobs screen for customers does not show jobs

or

The jobs screen for customers does not shows jobs

PS: Are there any other errors in my post ?

Comment: The "does not show" is a coherent finite verb phrase, forming a predicate and taking "the customer job screen" as its subject.  The "does not shows" isn't coherent.  It has two finite verbs with no established relationship between them, and there aren't enough available subjects for the two predicates that they try to form.  In a finite verb construction, only the first verb takes a finite form and agrees with a subject.  The rest of the verbs in the construction are strictly non-finite: bare infinitives and participles and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is correct:

> The jobs screen for customers does not show jobs

The auxiliary verb (does) is marked for third person, but the main verb is not. It appears in its base form. A helpful way to remember this is that when there is an auxiliary verb, the main verb does not need to be marked for third person, because the third person is shown in the auxiliary. However, in a sentence about the third person(he, she, it) without an auxiliary verb, the main verb does need to be in the third person form, as in this sentence:

> He likes to eat pizza. (like, the only verb, is in its third person form)